# Set width to 100% to make it responsive in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so i have this code

```
<div style="text-align:center; max-width:500px; width:100%; margin:auto"> <script type="text/javascript" src="transition_example.js"></script></div>
```

this is the transition_example.js:

```
var show1=new slideshow({ 

wrapperid: "myslide", 
wrapperclass: "sliceClass", 
imagearray: [
    ["1.jpg"],
    ["2.jpg"]
],

pause: 9000, //pause between content change (millisec)
transduration: 1000 //duration of transition (affects only IE users)

})
```

i want to set the images to display at 100% width so when the screen resizes the js script resizes too.

Can't find a way to achieve it, i could really use some help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried adding `width: 100%` or `max-width: 100%` to the `img` elements in the slideshow?

Comment: Using JS? sorry i don't know what u mean

Comment: applied to your images using CSS. Maybe using `. sliceClass img { width: 100%; }`, but I can't tell if that will work without seeing the full source or rendered html/css.

Comment: Nail it, good job, thanks for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll submit as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make an image responsive to it's container, assuming your container doesn't have a fixed width, just add `width: 100%` or `max-width: 100%` to the `img`.

`width: 100%` will make the image as wide as the container, and it will scale with it.

```css
.sliceClass img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sliceClass">
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
</div>
```

`max-width: 100%` will make the image responsive with the container, but the image `width` will not expand beyond it's actual width.

```css
.sliceClass img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sliceClass">
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this css to apply a 100% to the sliceClass generated img

```
.sliceClass {
    width: 100%;
    img {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```